# Primary color change in ionic1 (Android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working with ionic 1 framework.. i need to set android primary color in my app..It's possible..?

[image]

Comment: First, you’ll need to setup Gulp and your app. The Ionic CLI prepares the environment for Gulp, but you have to install it yourself. Install the node modules needed in your app for this task.

npm install
gulp
This will build the CSS file into the www/css/ionic.app.css file, which you then need to use instead of the ionic.bundle.css file used by default.

Comment: My question need to add primary color for my app (android)..see my pictures..

Comment: @Balakumaran please read Smanta's comment more carefully, as that is the correct way to change those colors. In the default scss file is a very simple explanation how you can change it.